# create menu item with special characters in nwjs / node-webkit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js, nwjs

Is it possible in node-webkit to create menu items that contain special characters like "ü", "ä", "ö"?
When you create a new menu item with a special character in the label, it will display it like this (same goes for tooltips):

```js
var menu = new nw.Menu();
menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({ label: "Spalte einfügen" }));
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BitJh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to encode special characters in order for them to appear correctly.

The following should work for you:

```js
var menu = new nw.Menu();
menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({ label: "Spalte einf\u00FCgen" }));
```

You can use the table at https://unicode-table.com/en/ for others, it will just be `\u{Unicode Number}`